# Best practices with Maven dependency management for submodules

Tags: java, maven, mobile, automation

We are in process of building test automation framework for mobile applications, we are using **Maven** as build tool and also for dependency management.

**Description**: As of now we have got around 25 mobile applications, we are planning below maven project structure where we have framework module and common module which contains automation framework code which will be used across all the mobile application modules.

**Issue**: As number of Mobile applications increases, I feel the maven project structure opted below will be difficult to maintian as many people will be working independently on automating different mobile applications but they need to chekout all the mobile application modules in order to add/edit any specific module.

```
+-- root (pom type)
       +--- mobile app1 (jar type)
       +--- mobile app2 (jar type)
       .
       .      
       +--- mobile app25 (jar type)
       +--- framework module (jar type)
       +--- Commmon module (jar type)
```

**Workaround Solution**: We thought of building a  framework jar which contains framework and common module and all the mobile application will be dependent on the framework jar. The problem here is we need to make sure all the developers are using the same framework jar and any changes in the framework will be having impact on its depenednt. Again each and every module should be updated separately.

Please advice the best approach where we make use of more reusability and less manitenance with regards to our framework and dependent modules.

Comment: Are those mobile App1...25 independent from each other ? framework and common are code libs which are used of those app1..25 apps.

Comment: Yes.. All mobile apps are independent, framework and common contains code libs and some common functions used by all mobile apps like login and logout steps.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the information that the apps are independent the setup you have decided does not make sense. Make every app a separate project (git repository) and defined the appropriate dependencies to the libs (commons etc.).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make sure that every mobile app uses the same framework and common module, you need to go with the multi module approach. Use `${project.version}` for dependencies to framework and common.

I recommend however to use the "workaround" you proposed. It has several advantages:

- As you mentioned, developers only have to checkout the code they are actually working on.
- They don't need to compile the framework and common module themselves as long as you provide artifacts in a (private) Maven repository.
- Framework and common module developers don't need to worry about breaking mobile apps as soon as they change their code. They build new versions of their artifacts and tell each mobile app developer to update the dependencies. The mobile app developer is responsible to make his mobile app work with the new framework and common modules.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and suggestion.If we go with the "workaround" approach, I was just thinking how do we run all the mobile apps tests in Jenkins.. is that something like we will be creating a separate job for each and every app and scheduling them independently? or do we have any other  best approach?

Comment: Yes, I would do exactly that: create separate jobs for each app and then automatically run them based on SCM commits. No need to build every app if only one app changed.

Comment: From the "workaround" approach, I believe updating the dependents with every change in the framework would again involve efforts. But from the maven structure mentioned above would show me all the changes which are supposed to make across the modules and we could sure all the developed test scripts are in sync with the framework.

Comment: I think the problem with the multi module approach is this: if a developer changes something in the framework or common module he also have to make sure that each and every app still compiles and that all tests run fine. Otherwise the whole project would be in a state in an unusable state. With the workaround approach the developers of the mobile apps will have to manually update the dependencies to framework and common and then be able to fix all compile errors and test failures.